# Extjs model association

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli, extjs4

I would use a association of model with extjs in my project.

If I use a model (select, insert, delete) eg child model will be updated and that it is the association with the parent and both?

[image]

My models:

```
Ext.define('ModuleGestion.model.Identite', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    uses: [
        'ModuleGestion.model.Genre'
    ],

    idProperty: 'idIdentite',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'Nom'
        },
        {
            name: 'NomJeuneFille'
        },
        {
            name: 'Prenoms'
        },
        {
            name: 'DateNaissance'
        },
        {
            name: 'LieuNaissance'
        },
        {
            name: 'Nationalite'
        },
        {
            name: 'CouvertureSociale'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mutuelle1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mutuelle2'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mutuelle3'
        },
        {
            name: 'Bourse1'
        },
        {
            name: 'Bourse2'
        },
        {
            name: 'Sexe'
        },
        {
            name: 'idGenre'
        }
    ],

    hasOne: {
        associationKey: 'idGenre',
        model: 'ModuleGestion.model.Genre',
        primaryKey: 'idGenre'
    }
});


Ext.define('ModuleGestion.model.Genre', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    uses: [
        'ModuleGestion.model.Identite'
    ],

    idProperty: 'idGenre',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'idGenre'
        },
        {
            name: 'Genre'
        }
    ],

    hasOne: {
        associationKey: 'idGenre',
        model: 'ModuleGestion.model.Identite',
        primaryKey: 'idIdentite'
    }
});
```